# Accessing system resources from ruby

Tags: c, ruby, rubygems, raspberry-pi, hd44780

I'm writing a ruby wrapper for Hitachi-44780 library for Raspberry Pi. The library itself is written in C.
I have the following code that tries to open `/dev/mem`

```
void setup_io()
{

   /* open /dev/mem */
   if ((mem_fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR|O_SYNC) ) < 0) {
      printf("can't open /dev/mem \n");
      exit (-1);
   }
   // Allocate MAP block
   if ((gpio_mem = malloc(BLOCK_SIZE + (PAGE_SIZE-1))) == NULL) {
      printf("allocation error \n");
      exit (-1);
   }
   // Make sure pointer is on 4K boundary
   if ((unsigned long)gpio_mem % PAGE_SIZE)
     gpio_mem += PAGE_SIZE - ((unsigned long)gpio_mem % PAGE_SIZE);
   // Now map it
   gpio_map = (unsigned char *)mmap(
      (caddr_t)gpio_mem,
      BLOCK_SIZE,
      PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,
      MAP_SHARED|MAP_FIXED,
      mem_fd,
      GPIO_BASE
   );
   if ((long)gpio_map < 0) {
      printf("mmap error %d\n", (int)gpio_map);
      exit (-1);
   }
   gpio = (volatile unsigned *)gpio_map;
}
```

The question is how can i use the gem without being a superuser? Now it fails when the memory is opened.

Comment: Can you change the permissions on /dev/mem?

Comment: @Fred
Don't think this is a good solution.

Comment: @Fred 
The permissions on the /dev/mem already set to `crwxrwxrwx 1 root kmem    1,   1 Jan  1  1970 mem`

Comment: I'm understanding you to say the open() fails because the process isn't root. If that is correct, what else can be done other than to permit a non-root process to open memory for O_RDWR? (Added: or making the program setuid root)

Comment: Sorry, we seem to be paying edit-the-comments! OK, what is the failure when memory is opened?

Comment: @Fred
I've set permissions on the test script: `-rwsrwsrwt 1 root       root   127 Apr  7 16:52 test.rb`
But still get `can't open /dev/mem`

Comment: What is the value of errno?

Comment: @Fred
It's EACCES 13 /* Permission denied */

Comment: If /dev/mem is rwx for world and you get EACCES, well, something strange is happening.

Comment: @Fred
I've noticed that after reboot the permissions for /dev/mem are restored to defaults. That is why I was getting EACCESS